# Java Timer Swing Exactly 60 fps

Tags: java, swing, timer, frame-rate

I have an animation in a JPanel that updates itself through a javax.swing.Timer. This timer can be constructed to have a delay in milliseconds that must be an integer. If I were to have the JPanel update 60 times each second, I would set the delay to 1000/60 = ~16.6666. However, this delay must be an int, so I have the option of rounding up or down. For a delay of 16 milliseconds, the animation would update at 62.5 frames per second. Rounding up to 17 millisecond delay would give a frame rate of 58.824.

How would I go about having a frame rate of exactly 60 frames per second?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The system timer typically has a resolution of ~15ms. So, you're unlikely to get the precise resolution you want anyway.

Comment: Even if the system timer is inaccurate, it should average out the errors over time (if my logic isn't wrong) and still give the same, undesired, frame rates (above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options which could help you. They ultimately achieve the same thing in the same way, but the code is more or less general. I haven't found any tool out there that does the job for you, so it requires a little bit of work.

The first option is to do something like this:

```
/**
 * Called by the timer when the next iteration is due. Assume that
 * this happens at the right moment.
 */
public void onTimerUpdate() {
  updateAnimation();

  // Compute the next point in time that corresponds to the
  // frame rate you want.
  long nextScheduledTimestamp = getNextTimestampInNanos();

  long nanos = System.timeNanos();
  timer.schedule(task, convertToMillis(nextScheduledTimestamp - nanos));
}
```

The second option is for you to get your copy of java.util.Timer:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Timer.java

and rewrite the bits that are millisecond-specific. Nothing in its implementation in OpenJDK shows that its resolution is millisecond specific, so you should be able to replace `Object.wait(millis)` calls with `Object.wait(millis, nanos)`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,%20int)

Interesting article, just for fun: https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks

Comment: This answer looks like for `java.util.Timer`, not for Swing applications which have to use `javax.swing.Timer`.

Answer (score -1):

It's not nearly as complicated as that! You can easily accomplish repaint() or whatever else method you need to call exactly 60 times a second with the single greatest loop in existence

```
while(true) {
    repaint ();
    try {
         Thread.sleep(1000/60);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

I call this in the main method of my script but basically it's an infinite loop since true will always equal true, then it calls repaint, tells the loop to sleep for a frame and then calls repaint again. And the 1000/60 sleep will result in this loop being called exactly 60 times a second